# Symfony2 - Render controller show blank page

Tags: symfony, controller, twig, symfony-cmf

I started develop in symfony now and i work in a CMS with Symfony CMF, i need to create a function with some lines in php and JS to insert into in running page or a existing template.

I created a Action at main controller for this template and i try render controller inside a twig with this line:

```
{{ render(controller('siteCmsBundle:Article:fish')) }}
```

But this return a blank page, i tried also this code:

```
{% render 'siteCmsBundle:Article:fish' %}
```

This return a route error (logical).

And the controller is:

```
<?php

namespace site\Bundle\CmsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Wf\Bundle\CmsBaseBundle\Controller\ArticleController as BaseArticleController;
use  Wf\Bundle\CmsBaseBundle\Entity\Collection\Module\PageCompositeEditorModule;

class ArticleController extends BaseArticleController
{

   ...

    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function fishAction(){

        return new Render("Test");
    }
}
```

Well, i'll continue to learn this framework, but i need conclude this issue today. :(

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your action is called `myAction`, you should do this : `{{ render(controller('CmsBundle:Article:my')) }}` (remove the `Action` suffix). Anyway, a blank page often means a server side error (500 error). So you should have errors in your logs (either symfony or apache)

Comment: Hello, sorry i edited the post now. myAction was an exemple.

Comment: `return new Render("Test");` ? Try: `return new Response("Test");`

Comment: Man! It's working!! But, i need add this line `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brewal and scoolnico :)

Comment: try {{ render(path('route_to_your_controller')) }}

Comment: Thanks Besbes. I'll try later.

Comment: look at the app/logs/prod.log or app/logs/dev.log files (depending on whether you go to app_dev.php or not) to see if you find a error message after calling the page. if not, look into the webserver logfile (apache, nginx or whatever you use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use annotation and just return single array.

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function fishAction(){

    return 
        array('fish' => 'saumon');
}
```

OR 
Add to method render() who extend of Controller class the template.

```
public function fishAction(){
    return $this->render(
        'siteBundle:CmsBundle:fishTemplate.html.twig',
        array('fish' => 'saumon')
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to use this options, but return "Page not found".

Comment: Add customize template  'siteBundleCmsBundle:Fish:fishTemplate.html.twig',
into site\Bundle\CmsBBundle\Resources\views\Fish\fishTemplate.html.twig

Comment: rommct, it's works! Thanks. But, the script tag doesn't work when i render controller with only <script>.